# Controlling object visibility with distance to other object's vertices

Tags: constraints, procedural

This is my first post so please forgive any noobish errors.

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a grid made up of hexagonal meshes. I have a cylinder that's either going to translate across the grid or scale up across the xy until its touching all the meshes.

I want to make it so once one of the verts of the cylinder gets within a certain distance of the centre of each hexagonal mesh the visibility will turn on for said hexagonal mesh.

The original method I was working with was using a limit distance and location constraints so that the hexagons would be pushed up in the Z and intersect with a Boolean object and become visible (which was working to a degree) but I couldn't get the limit distance constraints to work with the vertex group of the cylinder. It would only judge distance from the centre of the cylinder which doesn't work if you're intending on scaling the cylinder instead of translating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is ways to do this in Python, but I will explain a way I found to do it using drivers.

You can control the visibility of an object in the viewport and in renders by right clicking on the Visibility section of the Object properties tab and adding a driver.
[image: Visibility]

In the driver popup change it to Distance type.

[image: Type]

In this case I have an empty driving the 1st input of the driver, and the object I wish to change the visibility of in the 2nd input.

You can edit the distance between the objects that will trigger the state change in the drivers editor window. Also, the expression in my example has "var-5" which adds m units to the switching distance. (try it and see)

You can use CTRL-L -> Animation Data to copy the drivers to other objects but you will need to update them to use themselves as one of the inputs.

The hard part... If you want every vertex of your cylinder to trigger every one of your hexagons, then you will need to hook an empty to every vertex, then create one of these drivers for every empty, then copy and edit every one of them to every hexagon and edit those! Sounds like a LOT of effort.
There is probably other ways to do this without Python, but this is the way I found.

As I said above, Python would be much better for this.

[image: video]

Comment: Thanks for writing that well thought out answer Psyonic. I definitely appreciate the efficiency of python but unfortunately I couldn't code to save my life haha.
Im wondering if it would work to create an empty and use it as a driver for the mesh like your example. But then use a particle system to propagate the empties across the cylinder mesh and then use an array to duplicate meshes that are driven by the empties.